# about Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, task

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MultiThreadLog
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                    string str = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("fff");
                    Debug.WriteLine(str);
                    Log(str);
                });
            }

        }

        void Log(string content)
        {

            this.txtLog.Text += System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + ":" + content + "\r\n";
            this.txtLog.Focus();
            this.txtLog.Select(this.txtLog.TextLength, 0);
            this.txtLog.ScrollToCaret();
        }

    }
}
```

hi, sometimes, in txtLog, there are 4 lines, which should be 5 lines. Does anyone know why?
Thanks very much.................................................................................................................

Comment: if you try to access the UI control from a diff thread, you might get exceptions.

Comment: @Hybridzz: they won't, because they've disabled the cross-thread exception with `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing that's wrong with your code is this line:

```
Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

That exception is there for a reason. It helps you avoid writing bad code, i.e. code that accesses UI objects from a thread other than the one that owns that object. Don't do that.

The other thing that's wrong with your code is this line:

```
this.txtLog.Text += System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + ":" + content + "\r\n";
```

Two different threads executing that line concurrently can (and in your case, do) both retrieve the current value of `Text` at the same time, concatenate their new text to that, and then reassign the result to `Text`. Whichever thread reassigns last wins, overwriting whatever the previous thread (or threads) tried to write.

If you use `Control.Invoke()` to update the UI (i.e. to call the `Log()` method), then all that code will be forced back to the UI thread where it belongs, and your race conditions will be addressed atomically within the UI thread, preventing this sort of concurrent access bug. E.g.:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    string str = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("fff");
    Debug.WriteLine(str);
    Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Log(str)));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45807839/1521686) by @Peter is more correct and right way. But you can use the [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) in c# to synchronize multiple calls to your log method.

The lock keyword marks a statement block as a critical section by obtaining the mutual-exclusion lock for a given object, executing a statement, and then releasing the lock.

```
object test = new object();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    string str = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("fff");
                    Debug.WriteLine(str);
                    Log(str);
                });
            }

        }

        void Log(string content)
        {
            lock (test)
            {
                this.txtLog.Text += System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + ":" + content + "\r\n";
                this.txtLog.Focus();
                this.txtLog.Select(this.txtLog.TextLength, 0);
                this.txtLog.ScrollToCaret();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is not a good solution to the problem, because it leaves in place the more fundamental issue that the OP is accessing UI objects from the wrong thread.